# Inno Setup: 32 bit components are shown - though they shouldn't

Tags: inno-setup, autocad

Okay, the list of installable components have to be shown during setup according to an exisiting registry key and it works - somehow. 
 
This is my function which checks the key for each component, but 32 bit components are shown though the corresponding 32 bit versions of AutoCAD are not installed. Let's take case 8 as an example. The current installed version of AutoCAD is 64 bit, and my corresponding program shows up during the installation progress. Case 7 should check for installed AutoCAD 32 bit and my corresponding program is listed, too - but why?

```
function CheckRegKey(GetNumber: Integer): Boolean; 
begin
  Result := False;
  case GetNumber of
     1: Result := RegKeyExists(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R17.0');
     2: Result := RegKeyExists(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R17.1');
     3: Result := RegKeyExists(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R17.2');
     4: Result := RegKeyExists(HKLM64, 'SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R17.2');
     5: Result := RegKeyExists(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R18.0');
     6: Result := RegKeyExists(HKLM64, 'SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R18.0');
     7: Result := RegKeyExists(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R18.1');
     8: Result := RegKeyExists(HKLM64, 'SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R18.1');
     9: Result := RegKeyExists(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R18.2');
    10: Result := RegKeyExists(HKLM64, 'SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R18.2');
    11: Result := RegKeyExists(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R19.0');
    12: Result := RegKeyExists(HKLM64, 'SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R19.0');
    13: Result := RegKeyExists(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R19.1');
    14: Result := RegKeyExists(HKLM64, 'SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R19.1');
end;
```

end;

Comment: First of all, check what's in registry in real. On 64-bit Windows open `regedit` (which should be 64-bit) and check if there's a key in the 64-bit node `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R18.1` and in 32-bit node `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R18.1`. Both should exist according to your description assuming you're running a 32-bit mode of your setup. If both keys exist, this question is more to be asked on Autodesk support than for us :-)

Comment: Thank you! Yes, both exist and I'm not sure what to do now. I'll check Autodesk for further information, thank you! :)

Comment: You're welcome! Well, maybe you can try to check the key value based on [`this NSIS article`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Detecting_Autocad_current_version_and_path). If you'll be lucky, there will be a list of installation IDs where each version will have its unique ID (different for 32 and 64-bit versions). If such list exist, I can't tell, I couldn't find any.

Comment: I don't know if AutoCAD is one of these applications, but sometimes when you install the 64-bit version of an application it actually installs both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions (or the 64-bit version with a layer that lets it load 32-bit plugins).  Checking with Autodesk is probably the best strategy anyway though.